# Can't find the palette to alter new objects

Tags: mesh, interface, 3d-view

When you add a new object into the blender scene, normally on the tool shelf a window will become available where you can put in the objects size or number of vertices etc.

These options:
[image]

For what-ever reason, when I now add an object I am no longer seeing that area where I can alter the measurements. Currently I want to use the Spin function but I need to alter it but I have no way of effecting how the spin operates.
Does anyone know what I have done or how to fix it?

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you're seeing instead of those options?

Comment: press **T** to bring out the Tool panel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you resized the top portion of the tool shelf, and collapsed or shut the operator properties part.
If that is the case you should be able to click on a little plus button on the bottom of the tool shelf and get it back. Then you can drag the separator to resize the operator properties.
[image]

Comment: That was exactly what had happened! Thanks for the Answer.

Answer (score 7):

Press <kbd>F6</kbd> button after adding a new object. This will display the same menu you're looking for in a separate window.

[image]

Comment: Ray, There is no pic to show really its just the same Tool Self as normal.

Comment: That F6 works as a perfect work around! Thanks.

Comment: Nice to hear that, but the fact is I solved your problem partially. The missing menu in the Tool Shelf is still an unexplained mystery :). Maybe you should upload your .blend file via http://pasteall.org/? We can than check out what's wrong.

Comment: @Rory If post helped you to solve your problem, please mark it as accepted using the check mark at the top left of the post.

Answer (score 4):

eeer... Just ran into this problem myself. On the top bar next to File, hit the Edit button. On the drop down screen find Adjust Last Operation, which will pull up the screen you're looking for. <kbd>F9</kbd> for the Shortcut. VER 2.8+. Cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard shortcut to bring out the tool panel is <kbd>T</kbd>

[image]