# How do I activate the editing box at bottom of "Tools" section?

Tags: interface, edit-mode

When I add a new item (sphere, cube etc) the lower left hand editing box is no longer activated....it is clouded over and unresponsive. For example: I add a UV Sphere but can no longer change the segments, rings, size etc. It was working in the past which makes me wonder if I have inadvertently turned it off....I have closed and reopened Blender but cannot rectify this issue.

Comment: There should be a litte + sign at the bottom, try to click on it and drag it upwards.

Comment: Related answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23037/cant-find-the-palette-to-alter-new-objects

Comment: I tried the "+" sign but it just opened a new window.

Answer (score 0):

in 3D view, use <kbd>T</kbd> to make the toolshlef appear/disapear.
[image]
You can also use <kbd>F6</kbd> to get the specific toolbox for new objects
[image]

Comment: T key is fine but the area at the bottom is greyed out and unresponsive....I have MacBook Air and have activated the top number row but F6 does not work.....any other ways?

Comment: you'd better try to load factory settings from file menu, you probably did something wrong.

Comment: Got the F6 working but the box that appears is cloudy grey and unresponsive....I can read all the stuff in it as the illustrated box above but it is cloudy and dead.....

Comment: Thanks for the help....I will re load the factory settings as suggested..

Comment: be careful when you install addons or change settings, always check if the problem comes back