# BGE python: get list of vertices

Tags: python, game-engine

i want to iterate through every single vertex of an object and then store them in a list.

what I have so far is:

```
for mesh in object.meshes:
   for m_index in range(len(mesh.materials)):
      for v_index in range(mesh.getVertexArrayLength(m_index)):

         vertex = mesh.getVertex(m_index, v_index)
```

now i understand that "v_index" gets me "vertex 0 through 23" of the object (its a cube), but how can i store the result in a list?

```
vertex_list(0,1,2,3,4...23)
```

thanks for any hint,

sputi

Comment: what i want to do ist to simultaneously shift vertices 0-3 and 4-7 by an X value  so that the shape don't breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not blender specific, it is a basic python list operation. Start by creating an empty list, then append each item.

```
verts = []
for mesh in object.meshes:
    for m_index in range(len(mesh.materials)):
        for v_index in range(mesh.getVertexArrayLength(m_index)):
            verts.append(mesh.getVertex(m_index, v_index))
```

You may also want to adjust them as you go instead of making a list.

```
posadjust = [0,1,2,3]
negadjust = [4,5,6,7]
for mesh in object.meshes:
    for m_index in range(len(mesh.materials)):
        for v_index in range(mesh.getVertexArrayLength(m_index)):
            if v_index in posadjust:
                vertex = mesh.getVertex(m_index, v_index)
                vertex.x += 0.2
            elif v_index in negadjust:
                vertex = mesh.getVertex(m_index, v_index)
                vertex.x -= 0.2
```

Comment: thank you, very helpful! However they are in a strange order... how do I know which vertex is where on my cube??

Comment: By looking at them in edit mode. How to view and sort them is [explained here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/36577/935).

Comment: I've already read that to completion, however it only explains how to see the order of the INDEX (one number per corner) and not of the VERTEX (3 numbers per corner, 3 vertices from 3 faces... ). I always seem to get the same answer that doesn't really help me - Or do I get something completely wrong here??

Comment: kind of a solution: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?381967-Order-of-vertices-in-a-mesh&p=2941519&highlight=#post2941519

Comment: @Sputi a vertex has one index which is it's position in the list of vertices. One vertex can have many edges connected to it, that is edge 1,3,6 and 7 can all connect to vertex 4. A face is then surrounded by a list of edges with vertices at each corner. When displaying the indices in the 3dview only the selected items will be shown, which is based on the selection type/s chosen.