# In Cycles, how can you make Particles Emit Starting from the Left to the Right?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, particles

I'm using the explode modifier and I want to try to make my object explode from left to right. I know you can do this with gradient textures but the only tutorial I saw either used Blender Render or was outdated. Does anyone know how you could achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same workflow seen for Blender Render

[image]

The ParticleSystem texture's editor is **the same** for both render engines (as it is for many things that don't involve shading properties)

[image]

[image]

Comment: That makes sense. Sorry I don't really understand all the differences between the engines yet. thanks for the answer

Comment: Don't worry, sometimes there are things not-shading related that changes between the engines (e.g. baking normals settings) because of the way they are coded, but generally developers try to keep as many things is possible in common

Comment: @Carlo FYI, see my answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38874/2217) to do it without any textures.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to do anything special to the partial system. Just have the particle type set to *Emitter* and emitting from the vertices with *Random* unchecked.

The particles are emitting from the vertices according to the [vertices' indexes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36599/2217), so if you reorder the indexes it will explode in a different order.

Reordering the indexes is very easy. Just select the whole object, then as explained in [my answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36599/2217), just go to the 3D view header then *Mesh* > *Sort Elements* > *View X axis* (or accessible via the search menu).
That is all it takes to reorder particles. However you will now need to press the *Refresh* button on the Explode modifier.

Here is a animated gif showing the difference before ordering the indexes and then after the indexes have been ordered.
[image: animated gif]

Comment: Nice! Surely this the fastes way to get the result.