# Blender Game Engine: Order of vertices in a mesh

Tags: python, game-engine

I have built some kind of random shape generator which in realtime alters the shape of a cube with 60 vertices.
However I've noticed that the vertices aren't in any specific order (or are they?) so that getting them is a real pain in the *ss.

The order for the top row for example is:

```
top_left = [23, 40, 48]
top_middle = [20, 37]
top_right = [24, 36, 43]
```

But it would make sense if they'd be ordered from 0 to 8...?

Do I miss something or what is the system of blender applying order to the vertices of a given shape?

I'd like to skip the step of assigning all the single vertices to a variable by hand, but therefore I'd need to know how the vertices are ordered in a mesh...

Comment: [How are vertex indices determined?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/36577/2217) may be of help.

Comment: Hm thanks, seems like a good start. However, how do I know what number a vertex has by  looking at the indicies of an edge?

Comment: or differently: ist there a way to move indicies around by bge python rather than moving every single vertex?

Comment: using armatures and shapekeys are common ways to move parts of a mesh.

Comment: Well that's not an option for what I want to do... I have trouble to explain this because english isn't my first language. But what would I do if I have a cube and I want to pull one edge (containing 3 vertices) say x + 1 by python? My solution is to get all the three vertices from that edge and assign a new value to them.  Or is there an easier way? Without having to get all three vertices first (which are in some strange order I have to figure out firs and formoust)? Can I do something with the Indicies?

Comment: solution: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?381967-Order-of-vertices-in-a-mesh&p=2941519&highlight=#post2941519