# Re-arranging Vertices

Tags: vertices, faces

I have modeled a low poly sword and now need to use it with a certain game engine. The game engine doesn't accept face indices and it is auto generated on runtime. (triangles only)

All existing weapons with the game engine has a incremental face indices, for example:

```
# weapon0
f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3
f 4/4/4 5/5/5 6/6/6
f 7/7/7 8/8/8 9/9/9
f 10/10/10 11/11/11 12/12/12
f 13/13/13 14/14/14 15/15/15
...
f 565/565/565 566/566/566 567/567/567
f 568/568/568 569/569/569 570/570/570
```

And the vertices are always `number_of_faces * 2`. And for texture mapping it only accepts u and v. w is always defaulted to 0.

Questions:

- Is there an automated script in blender that can re-arrange my model to follow this format?
- If there is no existing script, is it possible to do if i made a script? what should the logic be?
- If it's not possible with a script, how should I have modeled the weapon, or what technique in modeling should I use to achieve the incremental face indices pattern and `number_of_vertices = (number_of_faces * 2)` pattern?

## My Model

The number of vertices on sword I modeled is 100. 184 texture vertices with w that is constant to `0.999501`. And the faces looks like this:

```
s 1
f 36/36 37/37 55/55 35/35
s 4
f 56/56 3/3 4/4 5/5
s 1
f 7/7 57/57 56/56 6/6
f 37/37 38/38 53/53 55/55
s 4
f 54/54 2/2 3/3 56/56
f 33/33 34/34 55/55 58/58
s 2
f 16/16 40/40 44/44 15/15
f 62/62 45/45 44/44 61/61
f 45/45 14/14 15/15 44/44
...
f 38/177 98/178 51/51
s 2
f 38/101 77/114 98/179
s 4
f 2/2 52/52 99/181
s 16
f 2/183 99/184 78/115
# total of 147 faces
```

Thank you.

Comment: What game engine? You would think they'd have some documentation on how to import models into their pipeline. You may find this post helpful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36577/how-are-vertex-indices-determined

Comment: The engine is some old engine from year 2000. No documentations too. And the post is quite helpful, I thought of some ways to rebuild the mesh using python so the indices will be re-ordered.

Comment: I also want to know how to do that?

Comment: @ULISESGARCIA there is a program that has a function that can re order vertices of a 3D model. Search for Noesis.