# Does Blender guarantee the order of the vertices around a polygon?

Tags: vertices, faces, edges

When looping through the vertices of a polygon via polygon.vertices, does Blender guarantee that the order of the vertex indices is consecutive around the edge of the polygon?

```
ob = bpy.context.object
face = ob.data.polygons[0]
for v_ind in face.vertices:
    this_xyz = ob.data.vertices[v_ind]
```

And same question for the edges of a polygon.

They seem to be for the cases I have checked, but I have been unable to find this documented anywhere.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: this might help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36577/how-are-vertex-indices-determined

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Unfortunately, I'm working in one of the ".. list too long.." situations.  My many-sided polygons were generated via the boolean intersect modifier, but I can guarantee that they have not been modified since creation.  In this case, can I count on Blender to have ordered the polygon vertex indices consecutively?

Comment: I am not sure. Hopefully someone else can chime in here.