# Displaying vertex indices in Blender 2.8 using debug mode

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to enable debug mode in blender 2.8 in order to see vertex indices in edit mode and from the instructions I'm following I'm supposed to execute `bpy.app.debug = True` but I still cannot see the indices. How do I do this in blender 2.8?

Answer (score 12):

You need to enable **Developer Extras** in the Interface settings, then you can enable vertex indices in the Viewport Overlays panel from the 3D viewport. You don't need to set the `bpy.app.debug` flag. Also, make sure to be in the **Edit Mode**. **Object Mode** will not show any vertex-related options.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This developer tab isn't visible on my viewport overlay window... how can I make it appear?

Comment: It works now, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Overlays are a new feature of 2.8**

Setting [vertex indices overlay](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/158495/15543) via script

Test script. Sets on for all 3d views in screen.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
for a in context.screen.areas:
    if a.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        overlay = a.spaces.active.overlay
        overlay.show_extra_indices = True
```

Setting debug is only necessary for versions prior to 2.8