# How to see source code of menu blender 2.8.1?

Tags: scripting

In previous versions of Blender, you could see source code of a menu by right clicking and select view sources from a dropdown menu. How can you do it with Blender 2.8.1?

Comment: Enable developer extras https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/158495/15543

Comment: that works thanks!