# How can I order the vertex index?

Tags: scripting

I'm new around here. I wanted to ask if there is any way to order the vertex index in this way? [image]

Comment: see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36577/how-are-vertex-indices-determined

Answer (score 4):

**Bmesh version**

[image]

Here is a bmesh version of [@3fingeredfrog's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/178278/15543) using method suggested here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36619/15543

Orders based on distance from scene cursor.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
ob = context.edit_object
mw = ob.matrix_world
cloc = mw.inverted() @ scene.cursor.location
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
#bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
verts = sorted(bm.verts, key=lambda v: (v.co - cloc).length)

for i, v in enumerate(verts):
    v.index = i
bm.verts.sort()
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Could maually select all vertices in order (one by one) and retrieve from the select history

```
verts = [e for e in bm.select_history if isinstance(e, bmesh.types.BMVert)]
```

The order in question appears to be that next is furthest of all the connected verts if not visited.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, yes, by ordering the index number of each vertex relative to its distance from the 3D cursor.

1: From the **Viewport Overlays** menu > **Developer** > enable the **Indices** option. The index number of each selected vertex will now be displayed in blue.

[image]

2: Position the 3D Cursor so that it is closest to "v1" and "v2" is the next closest ..........

3: In **Edit mode** and with the vertices selected: open the **Mesh** menu > **Sort Elements** > choose the **Cursor Distance** option.

now v1=0 v2=1 v3=2 v4=3 etc

[image]

Comment: Good answer, but the questions tag says *scripting*. Do you have any input on a scripting approach? E.g. how to position the 3D Cursor and call that operation with python?

Comment: oppps, I missed that @Dark -Z was looking for a scripting solution and have no idea how to do that with python.

Comment: thanks for the information, I work by doing it manually but do not know of the existence of any python script that does this job?

Comment: I need a script because there are many mesh that I need to order the index