# (Python API 2.82a)how to pin vertex group with python api

Tags: python, cloth-simulation, vertex-groups

how to pin a **vertex group** in **Cloth modifier** with **python** API?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick minimum working example with Blender 2.82a and Python:

```
import bpy

def clear_scene():
    for block in bpy.data.meshes:
        if block.users == 0:
            bpy.data.meshes.remove(block)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

def make_cloth(vertices):
    """Make a plane at height 0.2m and subdivide. Then, pin vertices."""
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(location=(0, 0, 0.2))
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=20)
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='CLOTH')

    # Pin the designated vertices.
    gripped_group = bpy.context.object.vertex_groups.new(name='Pinned')
    gripped_group.add(vertices, 1.0, 'ADD')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Cloth"].settings.vertex_group_mass = 'Pinned'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    clear_scene()
    vertices = [0]
    make_cloth(vertices)
```

*Note*: the `clear_scene` method is not necessary to get pinned vertices. I just had it there to remove the starting items so that the only thing left would be the cloth.

If this file is called `test.py`, then run `blender -P test.py`. I get this when I open the GUI:

[image]

Notice the vertex groups shown to the right in the screenshot above.

Clicking the "play"' button to animate the scene, I get this at frame 85:

[image]

Unfortunately, it isn't always clear how vertex *indices* are determined. I would [consult this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36577/how-are-vertex-indices-determined) for further information.

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER I added some text there to explain.

Comment: Cheers, a little warning like This will clear all your objects and meshes from the file too. lol.  Oh and recommend with modifiers and most blender objects, if you have a reference eg `gripped_group` above, then `gripped_group.name` will **always** be that refs name.  eg if for example by chance there is an existing group named "Pinned".  Realise it can't happen here, .. simply think it's a good habit to get into with rt blender's naming convention as it is.  A grid primitive will remove the need to mode swap subdiv.