# Face index unchaged after modifying it

Tags: add-on

I'm currently working on an Addon that handles polyhedra and I need to change the faces' indices in order to keep my structure coherent when the user does operations like extrusion, etc...

So far I have this Operator that basically modifies the index of every face that is selected by the user.

```
class Extrude(Operator):
    def execute(self, context):
        context = bpy.context
        obj = context.edit_object
        me = obj.data
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

        # list of selected faces
        selfaces = [f for f in bm.faces if f.select]
        if selfaces:
            for f in selfaces :
                    f.index = something

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

During the method's execution the indices are modified, but at the end the indices are back to their original values. I tried using `bm.faces.index_update()` but it still does not work. Is their a way to make these index changes permanent ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Call sort, not index update.**

Exactly as explained here, https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36619/15543 can set all of a  `BMVert, BMEdge, BMFace` indices and then call collections  sort to have new order.

Here is an example that simply shuffles all face indices

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from random import shuffle
from bpy import context

ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

indices = list(range(len(bm.faces)))
shuffle(indices)
for i, f in zip(indices, bm.faces):
    f.index = i
    
bm.faces.sort()
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

- Suggest index update method is designed to "re-validate" or ensure the indices of the bmesh sequence, *eg* n faces have indices `f.index` in `range(n)`  It's partner in crime is `ensure_lookup_table` which is required before indexing a sequence `bm.faces[index]`.
- Update edit mesh to apply the changes.
- Question "code" offers up some questions? What is the expected result  for a 100 face mesh with only 10 faces selected. How are the 90 other "somethings" ordered?  Maybe by swapping values, *eg*

  ```
   v[i].index, v[j].index = j, i
  ```

Comment: Another thing re question code, wouldn't bother with `if selfaces:` since `for x in []:` will not do anything anyway.

Comment: It finally works, thank you so much !
Wassim