Alpha Blend and Alpha Hashed draw order
I'm looking for solution to my problem that is similar to this one: Weird squares show up with alpha blend
But my model is a cup lid with locker, future .gltf export. 2 meshes, both need to be transparent. As far as I can investigate, this problem occur when draw order is wrong. Alpha Hashed hide most of them, but not all.
So I'm interested what is the fastest way to fix that and how to avoid this during modeling process. Thank you.

UPD: Found out how to change vertex order with Phyton script https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36619/187010 and now suppose that I need to do something similar with faces from top to bottom by Z axes or from center to edges of the model.
UPD_2: With help of Chat GPT, looks like I've got correct script for my issue.
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

# Function to get the centroid of a face
def face_centroid(face):
    return sum((v.co for v in face.verts), Vector()) / len(face.verts)

# Get the active object
ob = bpy.context.object
assert ob.type == "MESH"

# Get the mesh data
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)

# Get the origin point
origin = Vector((0, 0, 0))

# Get the centroid of each face
face_centroids = {f: face_centroid(f) for f in bm.faces}

# Sort faces based on their Z-coordinate (from top to bottom),
# and then by their distance from the origin point (from closest to farthest)
sorted_faces = sorted(bm.faces, key=lambda f: (f.calc_center_median().z, (origin - face_centroids[f]).length))

# Create a mapping of old vertices to new vertices
old_to_new_verts = {}
new_bm = bmesh.new()

for f in sorted_faces:
    new_verts = [old_to_new_verts.setdefault(v.index, new_bm.verts.new(v.co)) for v in f.verts]
    new_bm.faces.new(new_verts)

# Replace mesh data with the new sorted mesh
new_bm.to_mesh(me)
me.update()

# Free memory
bm.free()
new_bm.free()

