# How to get to face select mode in Blender?

Tags: selection-tools, faces

How I get in face select mode in Blender?

Answer (score 13):

For those who are in the newer Blender versions (this is for 2.81), here's where the buttons changed to:

In a 3D Viewport editor, make sure you're in edit mode (usually by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>). The new icons will be in the upper left corner, just before the editor's menu bar.

[image: Vertex/edge/face selection modes]

Comment: You can also type 3 on your keyboard (Alpha 3 not Numpad 3) when in Edit Mode when in the Layout or Modelling Workspaces to get face select mode. Conveniently, 1, 2 and 3 on your keyboard (Alpha) represent the Vertex, Edge and Face select modes. You can see the workspaces tabs on the top right of the image shown in the answer above. This is also for Blender versions near 2.81.

Answer (score 6):

1. You can use the buttons in the 3D view header (highlighted in red) to change the selection mode.
   [image: 3D view header]
2. You could access the search menu by pressing wither <kbd>Space</kbd> or  <kbd>F3</kbd> depending on you keymap, and search for "Select Mode" then change the selection mode in the [operator panel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23048/2217).
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> for pre-2.79 toopen a selection mode menu, or <kbd>3</kbd> for 2.8 series to immediately enter face mode.