# Select mirror: Could it add to the selection

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools, mirror

Is there any way to make "Select Mirror" add to the selection, rather than just drop the previously selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the [operator part of the Toolshelf Region](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23048/2217) or press <kbd>F6</kbd>. Then click on the *Extend* check box.

[image: operator panel showing the Extend check box]