# How to pull up tool menu for vertices?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

I'm very new to Blender and am having a bit of trouble.
After I <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh > Cylinder*, I want to pull up this menu:

[image]

How would I do this, please? It doesn't just pop up after I add in the cylinder. Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23037/cant-find-the-palette-to-alter-new-objects

Comment: If you would prefer, you can press F6 instead, to change these settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>T</kbd> will toggle open/close the *Toolshelf*, and that menu is at the bottom of the *Toolshelf*.

Alternately, you may see a plus at the bottom of the *Toolshelf*. Click on it.

[image]

Comment: I have the toolshelf up, but the "add cylinder" section isn't at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Bjtatty Edited my answer. If it helped, please consider accepting it by selecting the checkmark in it's upper left-hand corner. It would help me greatly and make me very happy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>T</kbd> will toggle the Toolshelf, but in order to change the variables of the objects, you must make the changes directly after the object is created.

Comment: The option doesn't show up for me though. I tried pressing t directly after, and I also tried it with the toolbar already open. There is no "Add cylinder" menu showing at the bottom

Comment: Have the toolbar open. Switch the "create" tab. Click on the object you want. It appears. Below the window is a window titled "Add Cylinder". There are settings. This doesn't work? Also, what operating system are you on?