# Options for new objects not in the tool shelf

Tags: interface, 3d-view

When I watch a youtube video it says something like verify capFillType = NGon; but there is no capFillType at the lower left.  How can I find it?

I have an HP all in one, windows 7, using blender 2.78c.

Comment: Is [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23048/2217) your problem?

Comment: Note that F6 will bring a popup with the tool shelf

Comment: Note that those options appear only after object creation, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/is-there-any-way-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created

Answer (score 3):

You can find it on the lower left, see screenshot.

From the [Primitives](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/primitives.html) documentation:

> These options can be specified in the Operator panel in the Tool
>   Shelf, which appears when the object is created.

[image]