# How to complete this hole with the grid around it?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

Is it possible to fill this hole with a grid?

[image: hole in grid mesh]

I tried with Grid Fill

[image: mess after grid fill]

With <kbd>F</kbd> fill (but no grid)

[image: giant N-gon after filling]

Comment: If the mesh is viewed from the top, is it still regular? Are the verts just shoved up the Z axis?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm no expert on this feature, so this is what i do:
[image]

Basically, i delete the faces so i can select the whole edge loop with one ALT+right click and THEN use grid fill.

Its about having the same amount of vertices selected on each side or something. But as i said, i dont really understand it that well xd Cause i would think "oh, i can do this":
[image]

Nevermind then...

Answer (score 10):

[image: a hilly terrain with a hole in it]
First start by making the hole match up with the underlying grid. In my case I Filled the two faces on each side, then deleted the one in the corner.

[image: animated gif show the start of filling the hole]

Now it is a simple matter of using the [Bridge Edge Loops](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#bridge-edge-loops) operator. Select the vertices along the two long edges, but not the corner vertices. Like this:
[image: proper selection.]

Run Bridge Edge Loops, either from the 3D view header *Mesh* > *Edges* > *Bridge Edge Loops*, or from the specials menu <kbd>W</kbd> *Bridge Edge Loops*. **Wait!** Before doing anything else open up the [operator history](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23037/2217) (bottom part of the tool shelf or press <kbd>F6</kbd>). Change the *Number of Cuts* to match the topology (in my case it was three), and set the *Interpolation* to *Blend Surface*.

[image: the hole after Bridge Edge Loops]
Ah that's looking better.

Last thing to do is fill the remaining holes. That is easily done in one step. Just select the edges (like I show in the image below) and run Bridge Edge Loops again.
[image: last selection]

Comment: That is the best approach I would have chosen. Clean topology.