# Landscape addon, tools don't show

Tags: add-on

My problem is that when I create a landscape via <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, I normally get my options at the right side of the toolbar, but now (has you can see), there are only three options and I cant figure it out, how I'm able to modify the landscape as I'm used to.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find the palette to alter new objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23037/cant-find-the-palette-to-alter-new-objects)

Answer (score 1):

There's a little plus symbol at the bottom of the toolbar. Drag it up